# (Asynchronous) NSURLConnection: what's going on underneath?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I understand that it must be taking care of the ugliness of launching a thread to make the network request, then probably calling `performSelectorOnMainThread:` with my delegate method.

I know how to *use* it when doing iOS programming, and it works great. However, I'd like to know how I would make it work doing in the context of (for example) a command line utility, where there is no UIApplication with the event processing etc.

I've tried it, and it seems that the program exits as soon as the asynchronous call returns, before the delegate methods can get called. I pretty much want a deeper understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-387826), the connection's delegate methods get called on the same thread that the connection was started from. So, to keep that thread running until the connection has time to do its stuff:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    // ...
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:del startImmediately:YES];
    CFRunLoopRun();    // Run this run loop, run!
    // ...
}
```

Then the delegate can stop the run loop when the connection says it's finished:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // This returns control to wherever you called
    // CFRunLoopRun() from, so you can still clean up
    // or do other interesting things.
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}
```

Comment: I realize this is strictly practical, and doesn't fulfill your desire for deeper understanding; I don't think I understand it any more deeply than you do.

Comment: Well, this shows me how to do what I wanted to do. I wanted the deeper understanding to (a) get that done and (b) curiosity. So this is still a bit help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The delegate method calls are scheduled on the runloop of the thread that initiated the connection. So it's not necessarily the main thread. You can do this from any thread. But you must have a run loop that is running long enough to handle those delegate messages.

And by default, the run loop has to be running in its default mode for those delegate methods to fire. So this is why, for example, by default if you start an async connection from the main thread, your delegate methods will not fire while the user is scrolling a tableview or something like that.

But you can change this by scheduling the delegate callbacks on any other run loop you want and/or any run loop mode you want using -[NSURLConnection scheduleInRunLoop:forMode:]

I hope that is what you were asking?

Comment: @Derrick, just to be clear this is because when scrolling, the run loop of the main thread is not in its default mode.

Comment: This is close to what I was getting at. Hopefully I'm not venturing too far outside the scope of my question. If I were to not be coding only using the Foundation framework (no UIKit, AppKit, etc), would I need to create a RunLoop to have NSURLConnection (and the like) behave (correctly) like it does on iOS?

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a run loop. But you would need to configure and run it.

Comment: @Derrick: If you're using an NSURLConnection in a command line tool, you should probably just use `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`, since there isn't anything else you need to do meanwhile (i.e., allow the user to click buttons).

Comment: @Josh Yeah I know it is not practical to do it asynchronously for a real command line tool. But the reason is I'm trying to writing a library that uses the aysnc version. I'm currently using a simple iOS application to test it. It'd be nice to do the development without a GUI or anything like that.