# Asynchronous calls not working in multithreaded section of code (MKOverlay canDraw)

Tags: ios, asynchronous, mapkit, nsurlconnection

I can successfully retrieve data asynchronously through `NSURLConnection` from any other part in the code base except in the `canDrawMapRect` function in my subclassed `TileOverlayView` class.

I'm modifying the `MapKit` sample called tileMap to download tiles from a server and overlay that information on the map.  In the `canDrawMapRect` I call a function in the overlay class which in turn creates the url and opens up a connection.  I have already tested my connection class and have confirmed that it does indeed work.  I've run it in the init functions of overlay and `overlayView` with success.  The urls are good too since I can throw them in a browser and they show the right pngs.  I know that `canDrawMapRect` is running on multiple threads and I only have novice experience with threads.

Here is my connection code,

```
- (id)initWithStringUrl: (NSString*) url {

    NSLog(@"Test Connect Init URL %@", url);

    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self loadURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];    
    }

    return self;
}
+ (UIImage*)connectSynchronousWithURL:(NSString*) url {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    NSURLResponse* response = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];
    NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];

    return image;
}
- (BOOL)loadURL:(NSURL *)inURL {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:inURL];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (conn) {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSLog(@"Connection Success");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed");        
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    [receivedData setLength:0]; 
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveData");
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn {
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data", [receivedData length]);
}
```

Pretty standards stuff.  If I run the code in the init of `TileOverlayView` it'll work just fine but if I run it in `canDrawMapRect` then none of the delegate functions get called.  I suppose it's also worth mentioning that the synchronous connection to the server does work in the `canDrawMapRect` method.  I don't get it at all T_T

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs about `NSURLConnection`, this pretty much sums it up.

> Note that these delegate methods will be called on the thread that started the asynchronous load operation for the associated NSURLConnection object.

Looks like I'll be needing to use `CFRunLoopRun()` and `CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());` to keep the thread alive.  Or find an alternative to making these async calls in the thread.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427168/asynchronous-nsurlconnection-whats-going-on-underneath)  Referenced from this link.